# Entity Framework query returning less results than expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an Entity Framework query where I'm calculating the grades for some students. The query is the following:

```
(
    from s  in Students.Where(a => a.GroupId == groupId)
    from q  in Quizzes.Where(a => a.GroupId == groupId)
    from qa in QuizAnswers.Where(a => a.UserId == s.UserId && a.QuizId == q.QuizId).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new Response
    {
        UserId       = s.UserId,
        UserFullName = s.FullName,

        ActivityType = "Quiz",
        ActivityId   = q.QuizId,
        ActivityName = q.Name,
        DueDate      = q.DueDate,
        Score        = qa == null ? null : qa.Score,
        MaxScore     = qa != null ? qa.MaxScore ?? 0 : 0,
        IsSent       = qa != null && qa.DateSent != null,
    }
)
.OrderBy(a => a.DueDate).ThenBy(a => a.ActivityId)
.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(a => new User
{
    a.UserId,
    a.UserFullName,
})
```

This query joins all Students and all Quizzes. I'm not querying QuizAnswers directly because if a student hasn't opened the quiz, it doesn't exist yet, but I need a placeholder to show on a report card.

Now, the query works correctly when I run it on LinqPad. In the sample I'm working on, it shows 4 quizzes and 700 students, and all entries are retrieved correctly.

However, placing the same query on the application (it's an ASP.NET MVC 4 app), when iterating the query, it shows all 700 students, but only the first quiz. I've also tried adding and removing quizzes, but it always shows only the first one.

Since LinqPad runs the query correctly, is there anything Entity Framework or ASP.NET MVC is doing differently? Perhaps an optimization, or a configuration or something?

Comment: No, it should behave the same way.

Comment: linqpad i think use database first, the project use what? database first or code first or ?

Comment: @MaciejLos, that's what I thought ,too.

Comment: @Fredou, LinqPad is referencing the DLL generated by the Visual Studio project. Both are EF Database First.

Comment: If you only  run `from q  in Quizzes.Where(a => a.GroupId == groupId) select q`, what does it return? Only the first quiz or all four?

Comment: @MichałKomorowski, it returns all 4

Comment: What version of EF are you using? is it the same for both ?

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker, EF 6, in both

Comment: I've just created 3 tables similar to your tables and run the similar query. The results seem ok. I think that the problem must be somewhere else and it may be so obvious that we cannot spot it. For example, a code responsible for displaying data can contain a bug. Don't be angry for this comment but it is always worth checking very basic things, For example if a correct database was used, believe me or not but I saw this kind of problems.

Comment: @MichałKomorowski, OK, I'm trying to look at everything in the method. It's not in the display because I've put a breakpoint just after the query, but maybe there's something before it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MichałKomorowski, I found the error. Turns out it wasn't the exact same query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I wasn't running the exact same query in both LinqPad and Visual Studio.

In LinqPad, I had `GroupBy(a => new { /* stuff */ })`, while in Visual Studio I had `GroupBy(a => new User { /* stuff */ })`, where `User` is a class not part of Entity Framework.

As I found out later, `GroupBy` requires a class with overridden equality, which anonymous classes have, but my custom class didn't have.

The solution is to override `Equals` in the definition of `User`.

Answer (score 0):

In VS  `GroupBy` should be `Type`

Change the order of your query a little bit.

Give this instead:

```
  from tt in ( from s in Folder.Where(a => a.GroupId == groupId)
   from q in Quizzes.Where(a => a.GroupId == groupId)
   from qa in QuizAnswers.Where(a => a.UserId == s.UserId && a.QuizId == q.QuizId).DefaultIfEmpty()
   )
    group tt by new {a.UserId, a.UserFullName}
     into grp
   select new
   {
       UserId = grp.tt.UserId,
       UserFullName = grp.tt.FullName,

       ActivityType = "Quiz",
       ActivityId = grp.tt.QuizId,
       ActivityName = grp.tt.Name,
       DueDate = grp.tt.DueDate,
       Score = grp.tt == null ? null : grp.tt.Score,
       MaxScore = grp.tt != null ? grp.tt.MaxScore ?? 0 : 0,
       IsSent = grp.tt != null && grp.tt.DateSent != null,
   }
   )

   .OrderBy(a => a.DueDate).ThenBy(a => a.ActivityId)
   .AsEnumerable()
```